# How to enable Kubernetes api server instances to connect to external networks via a proxy

Tags: kubernetes, azure-active-directory

The goal is to enable Kubernetes api server to connect to resources on the internet when it is on a private network on which internet resources can only be accessed through a proxy.

Background:

A kubernetes cluster is spun up using kubespray containing two apiserver instances that run on two VMs and are controlled via a manifest file. The Azure AD is being used as the identity provider for authentication. In order for this to work the API server needs to initialize its OIDC component by connecting to Microsoft and downloading some keys that are used to verify tokens issued by Azure AD.

Since the Kubernetes cluster is on a private network and needs to go through a proxy before reaching the internet, one approach was to set https_proxy and no_proxy in the kubernetes API server container environment by adding this to the manifest file. The problem with this approach is that when using Istio to manage access to APIs, no_proxy needs to be updated whenever a new service is added to the cluster. One solution could have been to add a suffix to every service name and set *.suffix in no proxy. However, it appears that using wildcards in the no_proxy configuration is not supported.

Is there any alternate way for the Kubernetes API server to reach Microsoft without interfering with other functionality?

Please let me know if any additional information or clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you would have Istio manage the egress traffic for your Kubernetes masters where your kube-apiservers run, so I wouldn't recommend it. As far as I understand, Istio is generally used to manage (ingress/egress/lb/metrics/etc) actual workloads in your cluster and these workloads generally run on your nodes, not masters. I mean the kube-apiserver actually manages the [CRDs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) that Istio uses.

Most people use Docker on their masters, you can use the [proxy](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client) environment variables for your containers like you mentioned.

Comment: The problem with this approach of using environment variables is that when a container wants to connect to the outside world each one would need to have the `no_proxy` and `http_proxy` env vars set. It makes it tedious to manage. I can't imagine the work needed to constantly update every single container env variables to reflect the new no_proxy values

Comment: Yeah, however the question is about the kube-apiserver only.

Answer (score 0):

We tried a couple of solutions to avoid having to set http(s)_proxy and no_proxy env variables in the kube-apiserver and constantly whitelist new services in the cluster...

1. Introduce a self managed proxy server which would determine what traffic goes is forwarded to an internet connected proxy and what traffic is not proxied:

   - squid proxy seemed to do the trick by defining some ACLs. One issue we had was that node names were not resolved by kube-dns so we had to add manual entries into the hosts files of containers (not sure how these were handled by default).
   - we also tried writing a proxy using node but it had trouble with https in some scenarios.
2. Introduce a self managed identity provider between azure and our k8s cluster which was configured to use the internet connected proxy this avoiding having to configure the proxy in the kube-apiserver

We landed up going with option 2 as it gave us more flexibility in the long term.